# how can i get the value for particular radio

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a form like :

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 padding_left_right_none padt18">
<?php foreach ($events['rows'] as $key => $value) { ?>
<div class="col-md-3">
<p class="event_id_data">
<input type="radio" name="event_id" id="event_id" value=" <?php echo $value->id; ?>" >
<?php echo $value->id; ?>
</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

and for radio value i am using this code on click of p tag but its returning me the value as undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input[name=event_id]').hide();

      $(".event_id_data").click(function() 
       {

      alert($('input[name=event_id]:checked').val()); 

       });
   })
</script>
```

what i am doing wrong here how can i get the value value for particular radio in jquery

Comment: `id` should be unique throughout the document, you assigning same id to all radio buttons

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with your rendered html using the [snippet button](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: See this : https://lishman.io/angular-2-input-binding

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach the event handler on the element it's self:

```
$('#event_id').on('change', function() {
     alert($('#event_id input:radio:checked').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign diffrent id's to your radio buttons you could do something like this

```
<?php $i=0;
foreach ($events['rows'] as $key => $value) { 
?>
<div class="col-md-3">
<p class="event_id_data">
<input type="radio" name="event_id" id="<?php echo $i; $i++; ?>" value=" <?php echo $value->id; ?>" >
<?php echo $value->id; ?>
</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```